# How to modify a StopLoss of an active trade?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql5, metatrader5

I have trouble with modifying the stoploss of a running trade using MQL5. Selecting the order works out for me. But if I try to access the variables ( for instance **`OrderTicket()`** & **`OrderOpenPrice()`** ), it always returns 0.00000:

```
2017.06.01 00:06:32.114 2016.04.08 00:00:00   failed modify  buy 0.00  sl: 0.00000, tp: 0.00000 -> sl: 1.41594, tp: 0.00000 [Invalid request]
```

Here's my stoploss modyfing void:

```
void modifyStops() {

   int total = OrdersTotal();          // total number of placed pending orders
   Print( total + " Orders on the line!!!" );

   //--- Over all placed pending orders
   for ( int i = 0; i <  total; i++ )
   {     bool isOrderSelected = OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES );
         if (  isOrderSelected )
         {  // TODO: Check the Trades to contain the correct Order Number

               Print( "Symbol & Magicnumber matching" );
               double newStopLoss;

            // Update the stop loss
               if (  OrderType() == OP_BUY )
               {
                     newStopLoss = addTolerance( SL );
               } 
               else if (  OrderType() == OP_SELL )
               {
                          newStopLoss = minusTolerance( SL );
               }       
               newStopLoss = NormalizeDouble( newStopLoss, Digits );
               Print( "NEW STOP LOSS::::=====> ", Symbol(), " at ", newStopLoss );

               if ( !OrderModify( OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), newStopLoss, OrderTakeProfit(), 0, Green ) )
               {
                     Print( "OrderModify returned the error of ", GetLastError() );
               }  
     }
}
```

---

The CTrade class isn't working properly for me. I tried to implement the code you've posted - however: It still doesn't seem to work out.

Unfortunately I implemented that in my EA and the OrderGetTicket(i) returns zero when the trade is live. So my void looks like this:

```
void modifyStops() {
for(int i=0; i<PositionsTotal();i++) 
    {
    ulong ticket;
    if((ticket=PositionGetTicket(i))>0) 
        { 
         //--- return order properties 
         double open_price    =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN); 
         datetime time_open     =(datetime)PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TIME); 
         string symbol        =PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL); 
         int order_magic   =PositionGetInteger(POSITION_MAGIC); 
         double volume        =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_VOLUME); 
         double stoploss      =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL); 
         double takeprofit    =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP); 
         ENUM_ORDER_TYPE type          =EnumToString(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE))); 
         //--- prepare and show information about the order 
         printf("#ticket %d %s %G %s at %G, with sl: %G tp: %G was set up at %s", 
                ticket,                 // order ticket 
                type,                   // type 
                volume,                 // placed volume 
                symbol,                 // symbol 
                open_price,             // specified open price
                stoploss,               //
                takeprofit,             // 
                TimeToString(time_open) // time of order placing 
                ); 
        } 
    }
}
```

And the printf function returns nothing:

```
2017.06.02 01:42:26.910 2016.04.07 00:00:00   #ticket 1 (non-string passed) 0  at 0, with sl: 0 tp: 0 was set up at 1970.01.01 00:00
```

I can't believe it's that hard to simply modify an SL in MQL5. That's horribly. However I need to get through it to test my strategy over several pairs...

Do you have another idea? I set up trades with the following code:

```
void createPendingOrder(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE orderType, double lots, double stopLoss) {
   MqlTradeRequest request={0};
   MqlTradeResult  result={0};

//--- parameters to place a pending order
   request.action   =TRADE_ACTION_PENDING;                             // type of trade operation
   request.symbol   =Symbol();                                         // symbol
   request.volume   =lots;                                             // volume of 0.1 lot
   //request.deviation=2;                                              // allowed deviation from the price
   request.magic    =224466      ;                                     // MagicNumber of the order
   //int offset = 3;                                                   // offset from the current price to place the order, in points
   double price;                                                       // order triggering price
   double point=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_POINT);                // value of point
   int digits=SymbolInfoInteger(_Symbol,SYMBOL_DIGITS);                // number of decimal places (precision)
   //--- checking the type of operation
   if(orderType==ORDER_TYPE_BUY_STOP)
     {
      request.type         =ORDER_TYPE_BUY_STOP;                            // order type
      price                =entryPrice;   
      request.price        =NormalizeDouble(price,digits);                      // normalized opening price 
      request.sl           =stopLoss;
     }
   else if(orderType==ORDER_TYPE_SELL_STOP)
     {
      request.type         =ORDER_TYPE_SELL_STOP;                           // order type
      price                =entryPrice;           
      request.price        =NormalizeDouble(price,digits);                  // normalized opening price 
      request.sl           =stopLoss;
     }
   else Alert("This example is only for placing pending orders");   // if not pending order is selected
//--- send the request
   if(!OrderSend(request,result))
      PrintFormat("OrderSend error %d",GetLastError());                 // if unable to send the request, output the error code
//--- information about the operation
   PrintFormat("retcode=%u  deal=%I64u  order=%I64u",result.retcode,result.deal,result.order);
}
```

Would it for instance be possible to save the result object in a Array and then access the running trade through that object?

Comment: functions minusTolerance(SL) and addTolerance() - do they loop over trades? check ticket number at start and before sending modify request

Comment: Thanks for your answer. MinusTolerance and addTolerance only add a few pips to a fixed stop price. There's no loop in these double methods. Like you can see in the first code section of the post - The selection of the order works without an Error, but the Variables don't contain any value. For example OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), or OrderStopLoss() all contain zero.

Comment: yes i understand the problem, that is why i adviced to check ticket at start and before sending. by the way, is it mql5 or mql4? Print("symbol and magic match "+OrderTicket()); to make sure it selects the right ticket

Comment: I firstly had another filter line where I checked whether Pair and Magic Number matched, but the funny part was: Whenever the trades went live - so they have been executed and not a pending order anymore - the OrderMagicNumber() was null and the same went for the Ordersymbol(). While the order was pending and unexecuted These methods return the correct values...

Comment: It is MQL5 btw. Okay I'll check the OrderTicket. What is it supposed to return?

Comment: either something wrong with your broker (that changes tickets magic), but i do not think so as magic is stored in client mt4 as far as i know, or you are doing sth wrong. so please provide a piece of code that can be compiled, executed, and still has a problem, and we will try to advice. now - this piece of code seems fine (except looping from 0 is bad practice, start from OrdersTotal()-1 to >=0

Comment: MQL5 do not have OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS) as far as i remember, it requires only 1 parameter (ticket id, ulong)

Comment: You're right with that one. In the documentation it says the only parameter for OrderSelect is the TicketID. I'll check that this evening and post some further code if I don't manage to get it running. I also read somewhere that I might have to make a cross at allow the EA to do live trading (even though its only in the strategy tester). I'm now guessing that the problem is that I call OrderSelect with invalid Parameters and only would need to call it with the "i". Gonna test that too and post an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in tester it doesnt matter if you allow trading or not, on demo account - yes you need to make ea smiling

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is you are trying to run MQL4 code in MQL5.

There are no `OrderModify()`, `OrderOpenPrice()`, `OrderTicket()` in MQL5!!!

See the documentation [here](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/trading/ordergetticket) on how to select, query values and modify trades.

you will need to be using `OrderGetDouble()`, `OrderGetInteger()` and `OrderGetString()` to query open price, stop loss etc.
e.g.

```
if((ticket=OrderGetTicket(i))>0) 
    { 
     //--- return order properties 
     open_price    =OrderGetDouble(ORDER_PRICE_OPEN); 
     time_setup    =(datetime)OrderGetInteger(ORDER_TIME_SETUP); 
     symbol        =OrderGetString(ORDER_SYMBOL); 
     order_magic   =OrderGetInteger(ORDER_MAGIC); 
     positionID    =OrderGetInteger(ORDER_POSITION_ID); 
     initial_volume=OrderGetDouble(ORDER_VOLUME_INITIAL); 
     type          =EnumToString(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE(OrderGetInteger(ORDER_TYPE))); 
     //--- prepare and show information about the order 
     printf("#ticket %d %s %G %s at %G was set up at %s", 
            ticket,                 // order ticket 
            type,                   // type 
            initial_volume,         // placed volume 
            symbol,                 // symbol 
            open_price,             // specified open price 
            TimeToString(time_setup)// time of order placing 
            ); 
    }
```

Orders are modified using the `OrderSend()` function https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/trading/ordersend

### Update

MQL5 uses a much more complex system of Orders, Positions, Deals and historyOrders. An [MQL5 community article](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/211) attempts to explain how they all relate to one another.

- Orders        = Pending trades (Buy Stop, Buy Limit, Sell Stop, Sell Limit)
- Positions     = Open trades (Buy, Sell)
- HistoryOrders = Closed/Deleted Trades
- Deals         = transactions that make up an order/position

To loop through and look at pending Orders:

```
for(int i=0; i<OrdersTotal();i++) 
    {
    if((ticket=OrderGetTicket(i))>0) 
        { 
         //--- return order properties 
         open_price    =OrderGetDouble(ORDER_PRICE_OPEN); 
         time_setup    =(datetime)OrderGetInteger(ORDER_TIME_SETUP); 
         symbol        =OrderGetString(ORDER_SYMBOL); 
         order_magic   =OrderGetInteger(ORDER_MAGIC); 
         positionID    =OrderGetInteger(ORDER_POSITION_ID); 
         initial_volume=OrderGetDouble(ORDER_VOLUME_INITIAL); 
         type          =EnumToString(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE(OrderGetInteger(ORDER_TYPE))); 
         //--- prepare and show information about the order 
         printf("#ticket %d %s %G %s at %G was set up at %s", 
                ticket,                 // order ticket 
                type,                   // type 
                initial_volume,         // placed volume 
                symbol,                 // symbol 
                open_price,             // specified open price 
                TimeToString(time_setup)// time of order placing 
                ); 
        } 
    }
```

To loop through and look at open trades:

```
for(int i=0; i<PositionsTotal();i++) 
    {
    if((ticket= PositionGetTicket(i))>0) 
        { 
         //--- return order properties 
         open_price    =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN); 
         time_open     =(datetime)PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TIME); 
         symbol        =PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL); 
         order_magic   =PositionGetInteger(POSITION_MAGIC); 
         volume        =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_VOLUME); 
         stoploss      =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL); 
         takeprofit    =PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP); 
         type          =EnumToString(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE))); 
         //--- prepare and show information about the order 
         printf("#ticket %d %s %G %s at %G, with sl: %G tp: %G was set up at %s", 
                ticket,                 // order ticket 
                type,                   // type 
                volume,                 // placed volume 
                symbol,                 // symbol 
                open_price,             // specified open price
                stoploss,               //
                takeprofit,             // 
                TimeToString(time_open) // time of order placing 
                ); 
        } 
    }
```

Hopefully, someone else will be able to provide a better explanation of Orders, Positions, Deals, history Orders as they still give me a headache.

To make it simpler I usually just create an instance of the [CTrade Class](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/tradeclasses/ctrade)

### Update2

Minimal example of trailSL for buy Positions using standard trade functions and Ctrade class

#### Init

```
Ctrade *m_trade;
CSymbolInfo *m_symbol;
Void OnInit()
{
    m_trade  = new Ctrade();
    m_trade.SetExpertMagicNumber(100);
    m_symbol = new CSymbolInfo();
    m_symbol.Name(Symbol());
}
void OnTick()
{
   m_symbol.RefreshRates();
}
```

#### Trail SL of Buy trade with standard functions

```
void modifysl()
  {
   ulong ticket;
   MqlTradeRequest request = {0};
   MqlTradeResult  result  = {0};
   double newsl;

   for(int i=0; i<PositionsTotal();i++)
     {
      ticket=PositionGetTicket(i);
      if(ticket>0)
        {
         request.action   = TRADE_ACTION_SLTP; // type of trade operation
         request.position = ticket;   // ticket of the position
         request.symbol   = PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL);     // symbol 
         request.sl       = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);                // Stop Loss of the position
         request.tp       = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);                // Take Profit of the position
         request.magic    = 100;                                    // MagicNumber of the position

   
         newsl = NormalizeDouble(m_symbol.Bid()-100*m_symbol.Point(),
                                 m_symbol.Digits());
         if(newsl>request.sl)
           {
            request.sl = newsl;
            if(!OrderSend(request,result))
              {
               PrintFormat("OrderSend error %d",GetLastError());  // if unable to send the request, output the error code
              }
            //--- information about the operation   
            PrintFormat("retcode=%u  deal=%I64u  order=%I64u",result.retcode,result.deal,result.order);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

#### Trail Buy Position StopLoss using CTrade

```
void modifyslCtrade()
  {
   ulong ticket;
   MqlTradeRequest request= {0};
   MqlTradeResult response ={0};
   double newsl;

   for(int i=0; i<PositionsTotal();i++)
     {
      ticket=PositionGetTicket(i);
      if(ticket>0)
        {
         newsl = NormalizeDouble(m_symbol.Bid()-100*m_symbol.Point(),
                                 m_symbol.Digits());
         if(newsl>PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL))
           { 
            m_trade.PositionModify(ticket,
                                   newsl,
                                   PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP));
           }
        }
     }
  }
```